# Почему в верстке, загруженной по XMLHttpRequest GET не работают скрипты?

Tags: javascript

Решил попробовать технику подгрузки контента без смены URL адреса. 
Почему подгружаемый script не отрабатывает?

При клике на пункты меню, контент загружается с помощью XMLHttpRequest с помощью GET запросов

```
xhr.open('GET', page.html, false);
//...
content.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
```

Код page.html

```
<p>Lorem</p>
<script>alert('test')</script>
```

Верстка у page.html вся загружается в место для контента. 
Но почему не работают скрипты с теге script?

Comment: Потому, что после такой загрузки все ваши скрипты, для браузера, просто строка. После загрузки вам надо заново инициализировать `js` методы, клики и другие ивенты.

Comment: как можно сделать реинициализацию?

Comment: как пример, поместить все ваши `js` методы в одну общую функцию и после загрузки страницы вызвать этот один метод

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Однако, не совсем понятно о какой странице идет речь - "После загрузки страницы". Ведь на первой странице пока нет подгружаемого контента. А на подгружаемом скрипты не работают.

Comment: Я имел ввиду **контент загружается с помощью XMLHttpRequest** т.е после данной загрузки вызвать функцию, в кторой будут все ваши ивенты, которые должны работать на странице